# How to export / download the chat conversation in aws lex using python?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-lex

Anyone can help to find the possible solution for export the conversation with lex in aws.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that you could potentially build yourself by making use of CloudWatch metrics and logging.

First, enable logging to CloudWatch for Amazon Lex. Here's the link to set for setting this up.

[Amazon Lex Conversation Logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/conversation-logs-policies.html)

Once you have the logs in CloudWatch, you can run queries on the data in Lex. Here's a link that lists some common queries that will get you started.

[CloudWatch Queries](https://awsfeed.com/whats-new/management-tools/analyzing-amazon-lex-conversation-log-data-with-amazon-cloudwatch-insights)

Using Boto3, you can query these metrics from your Lambda function. Here's the API reference for this.

[Boto3  - CloudWatch](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/cw-example-metrics.html)

Your Lambda function will need to organize the data to build up the conversation transcript in the correct order.